# Overflow when read adobe.stream

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code where I'm saving some data to my database but when I run the code I get `Overflow` error. Any idea what is the issue and if there is anything I need to add to make it better?

```
Open_DB MSACCString
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

'rs.Open MSACCString, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
Dim SearchID As String
Dim strStream As ADODB.Stream

SearchID = Card_Screen.Range("Sh_EmpID").Value

With RS
    .Index = "NA_EMP_ID"
    .CursorLocation = adUseServer
    .Open "ID_Card", cn, 1, 3, adCmdTableDirect
    .Seek SearchID

    If Not RS.EOF Then
        'rs.Fields("NA_EMP_ID") = Range("SH_EMPID").Value
        RS.Fields("First") = Range("FName").Value
        RS.Fields("Third") = Range("TName").Value
        RS.Fields("DOB") = Range("Sh_DOB").Value
        RS.Fields("PassportNumber") = Range("Sh_Passport").Value

        If Sheets("ID_Entry").OptionButton1.Value = True Then
            RS.Fields("EmpType") = Sheets("ID_Entry").OptionButton1.Caption
        ElseIf Sheets("ID_Entry").OptionButton2.Value = True Then
            RS.Fields("EmpType") = Sheets("ID_Entry").OptionButton2.Caption
        Else
            MsgBox "Please select employee type"
        End If

        If CheckFolder(Card_Screen.Range("SH_Photo"), Card_Screen.Range("Sh_EmpID") & ".jpg") Then
            Set stringStream = New ADODB.Stream
            stringStream.Type = adTypeBinary
            stringStream.Open
            stringStream.LoadFromFile Range("Photo").Value
            RS.Fields("Photo").Value = stringStream.Read
        End If

        Range("Photo") = imageToFile(TempPath & Trim(RS("NA_Emp_ID")) & ".jpg", RS("Photo"))
        Range("Photo") = Range("FName").Value
        .Update
        .Close
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: getting the error when excuting  this line RS.Fields("Photo").Value = stringStream.Read

Comment: What data tupe is the field `photo`?  Should it be `.readtext`?

Comment: As far as I know, *Overflow* error means you are trying to store a value which data type oversizes field/variable type; e.g. if you define a field as `Byte`, limit of Byte is 255. If you try to store value 300 in that field, it will raise error *Overflow*. So check how you have defined data in the table fields.